# Commit all changes to GIT via Python and capture Output

Tags: python, git

I have to come up with Python script that will Capture all changes to GIT. This script will be automated to run once a day.

I have come up with this but does not look satisfactory.

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import *

accpath = 'M:/STD1/GIT_TEST'
print (accpath)
subprocess.Popen(["ls"],cwd = accpath)
subprocess.Popen(["git","init"],cwd = accpath)

subprocess.Popen(["git","add","."],cwd = accpath)
subprocess.Popen(["git","commit","-m","'committed'"],cwd = accpath)

p = subprocess.Popen(["git","log","-p","-1"], cwd = accpath, stdout = 
subprocess.PIPE,)
stdout_value = p.communicate()[0]
t1 = repr(stdout_value)

v = subprocess.Popen(["git","status"],cwd = accpath)
std_val = v.communicate()
print(std_val)
```

Output is something like this

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working         directory)
#
#       deleted:    England/mana2.ttx
#       deleted:    England/test12121212.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Can you guys help me with this?
-Deleted 2 files but says No changes to commit.
-I am just looking for a clear output which can be sent as a report(mail).

Comment: In what sense is this not satisfactory?

Comment: @kabanus thank you for the edit.
The output is not satisfactory.

Comment: It's unclear what you're problem is - I suggest you be more specific than unsatisfactory.

Comment: @kabanus - edited the question.

Comment: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html